# What is scalability in Intel CPU?

Tags: cpu, scalability

Some Intel CPUs have a scalability feature such as [i7-4790](http://ark.intel.com/products/80806/Intel-Core-i7-4790-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz):

> Scalability:  1S Only

There is no explanation about what this is. Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/787313/intel-xeon-processors-difference-between-2s-4s-and-s2s-s4s-scalability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the *Scalability: "1S"* means it only supports single socket setups. So you cannot create a system with two sockets and fill only one until you need your system to **scale up** to handle more load and then to accomplish that, simply add a second processor. You can do that with Xeon processors though, for example [E5-2440 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75263/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2440-v2-20M-Cache-1_90-GHz) has *"2S Only"*.

Comment: Does '2S only' mean you can only use the processors in sets of (0 or two). not 1?

Comment: @Gizmo Yes, although 0 will probably not work very well... :-) However, the postfix "S" means "Socket". "S2S" would mean scalable 1 or 2 CPUs on a motherboard. [See here for details](https://serverfault.com/questions/787313/intel-xeon-processors-difference-between-2s-4s-and-s2s-s4s-scalability).